# ADT not updated in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using of *Eclipse* for build an *Android* project. but when I open Eclipse, following `error` displayed :

[image]

Due to solving this problem, I downloaded last version of `ADT (23.0.6)` and installed that in Eclipse from following :

```
Help>install new software
```

[image]

But again below `error` occurred :

> The operation cannot be completed.  See the details.

Details :

> Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
>   Software being installed: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515
>   (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
>   Software currently installed: Android Development Tools
>   18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)   Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
>       ADT XML Overlay 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay
>   18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
>       ADT XML Overlay 23.0.6.1720515 (overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay 23.0.6.1720515)   Cannot
>   satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Development Tools 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
>       To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [23.0.6.1720515]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Android Development Tools 18.0.0.v201203301601-306762 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature.group
>   18.0.0.v201203301601-306762)
>       To: overlay.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.overlay [18.0.0.v201203301601-306762]

I thank you for help.

Comment: Two ideas. First try installing the latest version via Android SDK Manager. If that isn't working out there probably is no harm in just removing ADT 18 and getting a clean install of ADT 23.

Comment: My country sanctioned and I can't use SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Previous version of ADT first and then installed that. This problem was resolved.